# Pending request on Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I'm building a website using Django. I have the register and login sessions working, so any user can create an account and login. But now I want a situation whereby when someone creates an account, the account will be inactive and pending until the admin accepts the user. However, I haven't implemented any code that does that before and I want to know if Django has a built-in package for that. If not, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a default `User` model of Django at time of create user, save it like these:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(
    first_name = first_name, 
    last_name  = last_name,
    email      = email, 
    password   = password,
    username   = username, 
    is_active  = False
)
user.save()
```

and by using filter query list all inactive users to admin.